# Oracle SQL, column name gives ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle, invalid-characters, quoted-identifier, ora-00911

I created a table through a pivot statement, which automatically creates some variable names that start with a number.

```
create table MYTAB as
select *
from (select x, anno, v, delta from tab_a13_2 where anno in(2017,2018,2019))
pivot(sum(v)  as v, sum(delta) as d for anno in (2017,2018,2019)) 
where ordine > 0
order by ordine;

select * from MYTAB;
x 2017_V    2017_D  2018_V  2018_D  2019_V  2019_D
1   1.01    -3.18     1.04   11.18    0.96   -6.87
2   1.28     0.09     1.28    7.33    1.25   -1.49
...
```

However, if I try to specify the column names in a select, I get this error:

```
select x,
       2017_V, 2018_V, 2019_V,
       2017_D, 2018_D, 2019_D 
from MYTAB;

Error at line 5:
ORA-00911: invalid character
           2017_V, 2018_V, 2019_V,
               ^
1 statement failed.
```

I don't get it. Either I am not allowed to create column names that start with a number, and therefore the table creation should fail, or I should be able to use them.
I checked that the column names are not quoted, i.e. '2017_V'.

Comment: Use double quotes.  Databases are finicky about identifiers that start with numbers -- or better yet, fix the names so they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: This solves it, I had tried unsuccessfully with single quotes. If you make it an answer, I will select it as the solution.

Comment: When PIVOT generates the column names it encloses them in double quotes. You can see the generated SQL by using `dbms_utility.expand_sql_text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) documentation:

> ## Database Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

...

> 6. Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

You have an identifier that begins with a number. This tells you that the solution is to use a quoted identifier and surround the column name with double quotes:

```sql
select x,
       "2017_V",
       "2018_V",
       "2019_V",
       "2017_D",
       "2018_D",
       "2019_D" 
from   MYTAB;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is that when you are creating the table, don't create columns that start with numbers. When doing a PIVOT, you can alias the values in the IN clause so that your columns produced from the pivot are more user friendly. Try to create your table by using a statement like this one:

```sql
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT x,
                 anno,
                 v,
                 delta
            FROM tab_a13_2
           WHERE anno IN (2017, 2018, 2019))
         PIVOT (SUM (v) AS v, SUM (delta) AS d
               FOR anno
               IN (2017 AS year_2017, 2018 AS year_2018, 2019 AS year_2019))
   WHERE ordine > 0
ORDER BY ordine;
```

Comment: Thanks but I was not seeking a turnaround or practical solution, but rather to understand the principle by which I am allowed to create a variable starting with a number and then not allowed to select it.